# AssertionError is not being Caught

Tags: python, function, try-catch, except

I have a function below and when calling it with the number 1 it is not catching the AssertionError, however it does catch when using Exception:

```
def func(value):
    try:
        assert value % 2 == 0 
    except AssertionError:
        print("failed")

func(1)
```

Failed never gets printed and instead the exception error is displayed traditionally on the console, why is that? Same for the below:

````
def func(value):
    assert value % 2 == 0 

try:
    func(1)
except AssertionError as e:
    print("failed %s" % e)```
````

Comment: That sounds like you're using an IDE or something else that handles the assertion it own way. (Also, assertions can be disabled, but that wouldn't produce the behavior you describe.)

Comment: It prints `failed` for me.

Comment: I am using wing IDE

Answer (score 0):

OK, looks like Wing IDE by default handles this exception like this, I need to change it in the settings, docs:

https://wingware.com/doc/debug/managing-exceptions